# SMTP protocol synchronization error in Exim4 when connecting from Gmail

Tags: debian, smtp, exim, gmail

I have a Exim 4.92 server running on a Debian machine, everything works fine. Now I want to send mails from Gmail through that Exim server, since Gmail needs an STMP server for alias addresses.

However, when I try to send a mail from Gmail via my server using SSL, I get the following error in Exim's `mainlog` file:

```
SMTP protocol synchronization error (input sent without waiting for greeting): rejected connection from H=mail-ot1-f48.google.com [209.85.210.48] input="\026\003\001\002"
```

I am not an Exim expert, and I don't have messed around with its configuration file so far. I am using the default settings I get from Debian's Exim configuration tool.

To enable TLS support in Exim I followed [this Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Exim#TLS_and_authentication). Thus I basically generated the certificate files and enabled TLS in the `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros` file via

```
MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = yes
```

Here is my `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` file:

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='...'   # my list of allowed domains
dc_local_interfaces=''
dc_readhost=''
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost=''
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname=''
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='maildir_home'
```

Any ideas how I can solve this error?

Comment: You are using implicit TLS (or no TLS at all) but need explicit TLS. Which ports did you set in your Gmail and which TLS settings did you configure in exim4?

Comment: @Lenniey I have updated my question accordingly to explain how I have enabled TLS support in Exim. In Gmail I select TLS as encryption method and used default port 25.

Comment: Is your exim setup to listen on port 587? This is needed for STARTTLS. You can check with `netstat -tulpen | egrep ":25|:465|:587"`.

Comment: @Lenniey No, it seems Exim is only listening on ports 25 and 465. Do I need to manually enable this?

Comment: Could you post your `update-exim4.conf.conf`?

Comment: @Lenniey I have updated my posting accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96563/discussion-between-lenniey-and-matthias).